# Getting photos from Twitter statuses/user_timeline

Tags: twitter

Using the Twitter API, I can get all the user's Tweets with location information. If they use a mobile app and attach photos, how can I get this from the API?

Comment: This is unclear. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: Sample with new API using C# ? another language ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you need to include `include_entities=true` as part of the request:

i.e. `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&include_entities=true`

Then, look for any `media_url` elements; those will contain the URL to any photos. It may contain video links, so you'll have to filter for common image types (.png/.jpg/.gif/etc).

See: [Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities)

Comment: This works for images uploaded via the web. Thanks. Looks like the android app is doing it differently and those images aren't exposed in the entities.

Comment: This API version is no longer active. It's now https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json

Comment: Sample with new API ?

Comment: The 1.1 API appears to have an entities object, but it does not contain any media keys. Even the docs on user_timeline do not state this is a parameter you can pass: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html - what to do?